# How to display a live streaming video using VideoDisplay in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, video, streaming

I'm wondering how to use a VideoDisplay object (defined in MXML) to display video streamed from FMS via a NetStream.

The [Flex3 docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/VideoDisplay.html) suggest this is possible:

> The Video Display ... supports progressive download over HTTP, streaming from the Flash Media Server, and streaming from a Camera object.

However, later in the docs all I can see is an attachCamera() method.  There doesn't appear to be an attachStream() method like the old Video object has.

It looks like you can play a fixed file served over HTML by using the source property, but I don't see anything about how to attach a NetStream.

The old [Video](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/media/Video.html) object still seems to exist, though it's not based on UIComponent and doesn't appear to be usable in MXML.

I found [this blog post](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/01/displaying-a-video-in-flex-using-the-netconnection-netstream-and-video-classes/) that shows how to do it with a regular Video object, but I'd much prefer to use VideoDisplay (or something else that can be put directly in the MXML).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can attachNetStream() only on Video object. So you are doomed to use em if you want to get data from FMS.

By the way attachCamera() method **publishes** local camera video to the server so be careful ;)

Answer (score 15):

`VideoDisplay` is a wrapper on `VideoPlayer`, which in turn *is* a `Video` subclass. Unfortunately, the wrapper prevents you from attaching an existing NetStream to the Video object.

However, a reference to that component is held with in the `mx_internal` namespace, so the following should do the trick:

```
videoDisplay.mx_internal::videoPlayer.attachNetStream(incomingStream);
videoDisplay.mx_internal::videoPlayer.visible = true;
```

(you need to import the `mx.core.mx_internal` namespace)

Comment: This works perfectly! Really ought to be the accepted answer. Thank you Cosma.

Comment: I'm getting a 1069 on the call to "attachNetStream", yet the audio IS attaching and the video isn't.  Since you seem to be quite sharp at these things I figured maybe you could help.  I can't figure out how to get a decent stacktrace out of flash.

Comment: The mx_internal namespace means that the properties and methods are not supported and could be changed in future SDK versions. Maybe Adobe changed the internal implementation of the VideoDisplay in the SDK version you are using.. I suggest to take a look at the sources of the VideoDisplay class in the your SDK distribution.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem too. How UGLY of Adobe to have at least 4 video players yet none of them having the API be used with NetStream and Flex.

Answer (score 4):

it works.

mx:VideoDisplay live="true" autoPlay="true" source="rtmp://server.com/appname/streamname" />

that will give you live video through a videodisplay... problem is it won't use an existing netconnection object, it creates it's own... which is what I'm trying to find a work around for.

Comment: also you can edit the source of the fly

my_vid.source = "rtmp://server.com/appname/"+stream_name;

like so... still doesn't fix the new NC for each display issue though.

Answer (score 4):

Here a link to example on how to use video:
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/01/displaying-a-video-in-flex-using-the-netconnection-netstream-and-video-classes/

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="vertical"
    verticalAlign="middle"
    backgroundColor="white"
    creationComplete="init();">

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

    private var nc:NetConnection;
    private var ns:NetStream;
    private var video:Video;
    private var meta:Object;

    private function init():void {
    var nsClient:Object = {};
    nsClient.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;
    nsClient.onCuePoint = ns_onCuePoint;

    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect(null);

    ns = new NetStream(nc);
    ns.play("http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/cuepoints.flv");
    ns.client = nsClient;

    video = new Video();
    video.attachNetStream(ns);
    uic.addChild(video);
    }

    private function ns_onMetaData(item:Object):void {
    trace("meta");
    meta = item;
    // Resize Video object to same size as meta data.
    video.width = item.width;
    video.height = item.height;
    // Resize UIComponent to same size as Video object.
    uic.width = video.width;
    uic.height = video.height;
    panel.title = "framerate: " + item.framerate;
    panel.visible = true;
    trace(ObjectUtil.toString(item));
    }

    private function ns_onCuePoint(item:Object):void {
    trace("cue");
    }
]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Panel id="panel" visible="false">
    <mx:UIComponent id="uic" />
    <mx:ControlBar>
    <mx:Button label="Play/Pause" click="ns.togglePause();" />
    <mx:Button label="Rewind" click="ns.seek(0); ns.pause();" />
    </mx:ControlBar>
</mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen sample code where something like this works:

```
// Connect to the video stream in question.
var stream:NetStream = new NetStream( chatNC );
stream.addEventListener( NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, handleStreamStatus );
stream.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError );

// Build the video player on the UI.
var video:Video = new Video(246, 189);
var uiComp:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
uiComp.addChild( video );
uiComp.width = 246;
uiComp.height = 189;
stream.play( streamName );
video.attachNetStream( stream );
video.smoothing = true;
video.width = 246;
video.height = 189;
view.videoPlayerPanel.removeAllChildren();
view.videoPlayerPanel.addChild( uiComp );
```

But I can't actually get it to work myself.  I'll post here later if I can figure it out.